# Горизонтальный вывод изображений разного размера

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

С версткой знаком поверхностно, поэтому возник вопросы как вывести изображения горизонтально, разного размера. То есть максимальный размер 45х45, но изображения может быть и 29х45, либо 45х33. Хотелось без лишних библиотек, сделать что-нибудь аля [пример](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Rolex-Mens-Datejust-16014-Steel-Watch-With-White-Roman-Dial-Fluted-Bezel-/181220094959), где главное и изображение и под ним дополнительные. Вот интересует список изображений как на ссылке. Методом проб и ошибок получилось, но к сожалению нельзя разделить ячейки. Сделал так:

```
/*---css----*/
ul.slide{
display: table-row;
height: 45px;
}
.slide li{
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    width:45px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
.slide li img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

ну и естественно

```
<ul class='slide'>
    <li>
        <img src="thumbnails/1379865497eknhh.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Может есть варианты лучше?

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает ваш вариант, тем что нельзя "разделить ячейки"? И что значит разделить ячейки? Добавить боковые отступы?

Comment: Да в общем-то устраивает. Просто может есть кошернее способы вывода, а я велосипед наваял. И насчет боковых отступов вы правы, хотелось бы

Comment: @xBCAAx, относительно вашего примера - при том, что это ebay, довольно странноватый способ они выбрали для реализации этой задачи: каждая фотография в отдельной **таблице(!)**. Меня это слегка удивило.

Comment: Я именно про внешний вид, внутренняя реализация конечно другая

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не изобрели велосипед, а используете достаточно распространённую технику для современных браузеров. Чтобы помочь вам в добавлении боковых отступов, есть css-свойство **border-spacing**, но беда в том, что оно используется только для таблиц. Поэтому для вашей разметки необходимо добавить дополнительную обёртку.

Накидал [пример на jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sXgu/). Подробнее про свойство border-spacing можно почитать [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-spacing).

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul class='slide'>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x45" />
    </li>
     <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x35" />
    </li>
     <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/45x15" />
    </li>
         <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/35x45" />
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.wrapper { 
    display: table; 
    border-spacing: 5px 2px;
}

ul.slide{
    display: table-row;
    height: 45px;
}

.slide li{
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    width:45px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}

.slide li img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Еще заметил все таки бяку, если изображения меньше 45 пикселей, то поднимаются вверх не смотря на vertical-align.